# Find specific files (including inside archives) and copy them to a specific destination

Tags: windows, gratis, file-search

I want a software for Windows XP+ that is capable to find specific files (`.epub`, `.pdf`, `.mobi`, `.djv` in my case) on multiple drives and inside archives and copy them all to a specific destination.